# How to observe Flow in Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-datastore

I have an app widget implemented using shared preferences.
Now I am working on its migration to [Data Store](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#preferences-datastore).

The problem here is how can I observe/collect the Flow data in AppWidgetProvider (a subclass of BroadCastReceiver)?

Minimum Code to reproduce the issue.

***MyAppWidgetProvider:***

```
class MyAppWidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
    }
}

internal fun updateAppWidget(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetId: Int
) {

    RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout).also { views ->

        val data = loadDataFromPreferences(context, appWidgetId)
        views.setTextViewText(
            R.id.textview_title,
            data.title
        )
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
    }
}
```

***DataStoreUtil:***

```
internal fun loadDataFromPreferences(context: Context, appWidgetId: Int): Flow<Data> {
    val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> = context.createDataStore(
        name = PREFS_NAME,
        migrations = listOf(SharedPreferencesMigration(context, PREFS_NAME))
    )
    val PREF_TITLE = stringPreferencesKey(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId + PREF_SUFFIX_TITLE)

    return dataStore.data
        .catch {
            if (it is IOException) {
                it.printStackTrace()
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            } else {
                throw it
            }
        }
        .map { preferences ->
            // No type safety.
            val title = preferences[PREF_TITLE] ?: ""
            Data(title)
        }
}
```

***Note:***

1. Data - A custom model class
2. loadDataFromPreferences() return type was `Data` when using Shared Preferences. Changed it to `Flow<Data>` for DataStore which causes error in `updateAppWidget()` in the line :
   `val data = loadDataFromPreferences(context, appWidgetId)` - as the data type has changed to Flow.

Comment: what is causing the problem ? code looks fine

Comment: @rajanks, I am unable to access the data as it is of datatype Flow<Data>. How to observe/collect Flow in AppWidgetProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **rajan kt**'s answer.
Started with the `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch` which was the main aspect of the solution.

But, `collect()` didn't work as expected. Tried with `first()` instead and it solved the issue.

Posting the working code below:

***MyAppWidgetProvider:***

```
class MyAppWidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
            }
        }
    }
}

internal suspend fun updateAppWidget(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetId: Int
) {

    RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout).also { views ->
        loadDataFromPreferences(context, appWidgetId)
            .first {
                views.setTextViewText(
                    R.id.textview_title,
                    data.title
                )
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
                true
            }
    }
}
```

***DataStoreUtil:***

```
internal suspend fun loadDataFromPreferences(context: Context, appWidgetId: Int): Flow<Data> {
    val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> = context.createDataStore(
        name = PREFS_NAME,
        migrations = listOf(SharedPreferencesMigration(context, PREFS_NAME))
    )
    val PREF_TITLE = stringPreferencesKey(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId + PREF_SUFFIX_TITLE)
    return dataStore.data
        .catch {
            if (it is IOException) {
                it.printStackTrace()
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            } else {
                throw it
            }
        }
        .map { preferences ->
            // No type safety.
            val title = preferences[PREF_TITLE] ?: ""
            Data(title)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collect` to get the data from `Flow`

```
val result = loadDataFromPreferences(context, appWidgetId)
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch{
   result.collect{ data ->
       views.setTextViewText(
            R.id.textview_title,
            data.title
   }
}
```